# Will the "arguments" object prevent garbage collection for unbound arguments?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, arguments

If I have a function `sum` that "takes" two arguments, then returns a promise that will resolve in a "long" time. Will any arguments passed to `sum` (past the two first arguments) remain in memory, and be prevented from being garbage collected?

For example, will `sum` prevent the "large object" FOO, from being garbage collected?

```js
const sum = (a, b) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(a+b), 500 /* Lets pretend this is a huge number */);
});

(async () => {
  const s = await sum(2, 3, {/* Some large object, FOO */});
  console.log(s);
})();
```

I'm assuming that because you can access FOO through the "arguments" object, then FOO would need to be kept in memory? However since "arguments" aren't accessible in arrow functions, would this behavior be different between keyword functions and arrow function?

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(...arguments);
      resolve(a+b);
    }, 500 /* Lets pretend this is a huge number */);
  });
};

const arrowSum = (a, b) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(...arguments);
      resolve(a+b);
    }, 500 /* Lets pretend this is a huge number */);
  });
};

(async () => {
  const s = await sum(2, 3, {/* Some large object, FOO */});
  console.log(s);
  
  const arrowS = await arrowSum(2, 3, {/* Some large object, FOO */});
  console.log(arrowS);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From a [twitter thread with Surma](https://twitter.com/Olian04/status/1308817140762513412) (a google engineer).*

**Q:** Would the "arguments" object prevent garbage collection for unbound arguments?
**A:** Yeah most likely. You can access `arguments` via eval(), so the engine/compiler can’t ever prove that you won’t access it and let go of the object.

**Q:** Since "arguments" doesn't work in arrow functions, would that then make arrow functions more performant in the sense that misuse by the consumer won't result in as bad performance as a keyword function would?
**A:** Theoretically, I guess arrow functions would have an optimization here that normal functions don’t.